# Date headers is getting converted to numbers after importing to R from excel

Tags: r

I have a dateframe in Excel as below

```
  Product   Location     Dec-2017     Jan 2018       Feb 2018
   A           B            45           54              56
```

Once I import to R I get below

```
         df <- read_excel("D:/Product and Mar.xlsx",sheet = "Data(P)")

   df
   Product   Location       43070        43101           43132
     A           B            45           54              56
```

I saw some stackoverflow solutions. But did not work out. So i reshaped this dataframe and tried to convert but did not work either

```
   df <- as.data.frame(df)
   df <- melt(df, id=c("Product","Location"))
   df
   Product   Location       variable     value
     A           B           43070         45
     A           B           43101         54
     A           B           43132         56

   df$variable <- as.Date(as.numeric(as.character(df$variable)))
```

But not working as well

Comment: what are you using so far to import from excel? (please edit your question)

Comment: try changing it to: ```df$variable <- as.Date(as.numeric(as.character(df$variable)), origin = "1899-12-30") ```

Comment: @Ben I have edited

Comment: @Insult-2-Injury Perfect but how did you know that we need to use 1899-12-30 as origin. Fine since i have reshaped the data, i was able to, but is it not possible to convert while importing itself?

Comment: It's the excel specific origin date, I am not aware of a package that allows you to convert to date while importing. You can write a function for that though.